# Spring Tool Suite 3.9 not working with Gradle Buildship

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite

i just updated STS to the 3.9 and i'm not able to import a Gradle project or open any Gradle related menu.
Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a few more details? You had STS 3.8.4 installed, including the Buildship plugin from Eclipse? And then you updated STS 3.9.0, using the "Check for Updates" feature? Or did you add additional update sites? I am just wondering what caused this. In case the Gradle menus just disappeared after the update, I would guess a wiring issue in the bundle level caused this (tricky to debug though). I would try a fresh STS 3.9.0 distro and install Buildship on top to see if that works, otherwise please open an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues with more details.

Comment: Yes i updated everything from STS 3.8.4 using the "check for updates" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new version of Buildship available (2.1.1) that also fixes this issue.

Comment: although the integration of Buildship with the Spring Starter Wizard in STS is broken with Buildship 2.1.1. I hope that there will be an update out there soon.

Answer (score 0):

We got an issue filed for STS that deals with issues using Buildship 2.1.x with STS 3.9.0, maybe that one is related:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/163

It looks like there is an incompatibility issue going on under the hood. Maybe that is also causing the problem that you observed here. I case you have Buildship 2.1.x installed, I would recommend to uninstall that feature. Then, after a restart, install Buildship 2.0.x from the main Eclipse Oxygen repository (via `Install New Software`).

Hope that helps in your situation, too.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" downloading a new zip of STS 3.9 and installing everything from the scratch with Builship 2.0.
Thanks for the advice! :-)